# the_content causes unnecessary spaces

Tags: php, wordpress

I used the code below to strip HTML tags from the_content() **but this creates unnecessary spaces while printing the result.**

```
  $content = $post->post_content;
  $content = preg_replace("/<embed?[^>]+>/i", "(embed) ", $content);
  $content = wp_strip_all_tags($content);
  echo $content;
```

By the way, I'm trying to print the result in a textarea.

```
<textarea class="form-control rounded-0" rows="8">
  <?php
  $content = $post->post_content;
  $content = preg_replace("/<embed?[^>]+>/i", "(embed) ", $content);
  $content = wp_strip_all_tags($content);
  echo $content;
  ?>
</textarea>
```

Any way to fix this?

Comment: Does the extra spaces come are displayed in the textarea? if yes just move the php code outside the textarea, also have it like this `<textarea></textarea>`

Comment: I tried that, but now it removes all the newlines(spaces).

Comment: Glade it fixed it, I will add it as answer, please accept its not left without answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Does the extra spaces are displayed in the `<textarea>` just move the php code outside the `<textarea></textarea>`, also have it like this